# explosion/throw animation on pic with javascript and css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: main goal]

i wanted to try this out  and somehow I have seen similar stuff with CSS circle on the web like

```js
function throwCircles() {
  const cube = document.querySelector('.cube');
  cube.classList.add('throw-animation');

  setTimeout(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      const circle = document.createElement('div');
      circle.classList.add('circle');
      circle.style.top = '50%';
      circle.style.left = '50%';
      document.body.appendChild(circle);

      setTimeout(() => {
        circle.style.transform = `translate(${i * 58}px, ${i * -48}px)`;
        circle.style.opacity = '1';
      }, 200 * i);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.cube {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  transition: all 1s;
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(50px);
}

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-50px);
}

.right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cube"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="throwCircles()">Throw Circles</button>
```

but the problem is how I will replace it with pictures. After I press the button, only then the first circle is visible, and it can't be visible without pressing the button. when the button is pressed it should be popping 2nd circle out

please need help on it

Comment: You can add pictures in your div with CSS: `background-image:url(./football.png)`. There are several options for hiding a circle. In CSS you can do `display:none` or `opacity:0`. I would also suggest using CSS Animation instead of `setInterval`: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp